# Not able to mount LVM2_member

Tags: mount, lvm, encryption

My disk got really borked, even grub is not responding anymore... So I want to take of my data of the old disk and do a complete reinstall (something I wanted to do anyway).
First I found out the name of the partition:

```
    root@kubuntu:/media/kubuntu# fdisk -l
    Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.86 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
    Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKNW020T8                     
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 2F317938-7F93-4301-A833-A6AB350EBFF2

    Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
    /dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
    /dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624    2549759    1499136  732M Linux filesystem
    /dev/nvme0n1p3 2549760 4000796671 3998246912  1.9T Linux filesystem
```

Found out it was encrypted with crypto_LUKS:

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# lsblk -lf | grep LUKS
    nvme0n1p3 crypto_LUKS 2                                    4c6e6d37-9275-45eb-acc8-                        ad3fc6a5f194
```

Tried to put a mapper to the unencrypted data:

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 mydata
    Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p3: 
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu#
```

Found out it was part of a LVM system:

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# sudo mount /dev/mapper/mydata /mnt/nvme/
    mount: /mnt/nvme: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

So did a few lvm commands to see if the partitions:

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# lvmdiskscan
    /dev/nvme0n1       [       1.86 TiB] 
      /dev/loop0         [      <1.80 GiB] 
      /dev/mapper/mydata [       1.86 TiB] LVM physical volume
      0 disks
      10 partitions
      1 LVM physical volume whole disk
      0 LVM physical volumes
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# lvscan
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vgkubuntu/root' [<1.82 TiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vgkubuntu/swap_1' [976.00 MiB] inherit

    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# lvdisplay
      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/vgkubuntu/root
```

Looks like they are active, so want to mount them:

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# mount /dev/mapper/mydata /mnt
    mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

And from here it gets hazy for me... And tried several ways to mount the partition:

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# mount /dev/vgkubuntu/root /mnt/nvme/
    mount: /mnt/nvme: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-                root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# mount -t ext4 /dev/vgkubuntu/root /mnt/nvme/
    mount: /mnt/nvme: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Just some extra info, no idea if it is useful...

```
    root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu# lsblk
    NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
    nvme0n1                259:0    0   1.9T  0 disk  
    ├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0   512M  0 part  
    ├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0   732M  0 part  
    └─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0   1.9T  0 part  
      └─mydata             253:0    0   1.9T  0 crypt 
        ├─vgkubuntu-root   253:1    0   1.8T  0 lvm   
        └─vgkubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm
```

Also used udiskctl:

```
    kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/nvme0n1p3
    Passphrase: 
    Error unlocking /dev/nvme0n1p3:         GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 is already unlocked as /dev/dm-0
     root@kubuntu:/home/kubuntu/Downloads# udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/mydata 
    Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d0 is not a mountable filesystem.
```

So now try to mount /dev/dm-0

```
    kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/dm-0 /mnt/nvme/
    mount: /mnt/nvme: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Stil hanging on the LVM2_member type...

Comment: Your `/dev/dm-0` is `/dev/mapper/mydata`, which is the decrypted view of `/dev/nvme0n1p3`.  It contains the LVM PV which has the LVs `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root` and `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1` inside it. The `lvscan` indicates those LVs have been successfully activated, so you should focus on figuring out why `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root` won't be mounted. First step is to try and identify the filesystem type: `file -s /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root`. If it's a filesystem type you don't currently have a driver for, that might explain why you can't mount it.

Comment: Hi telcoM, thanks for your reply! Did:

# file -s /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root: symbolic link to ../dm-1 

#file -s /dev/dm-1 /dev/dm-1: data 
So I tried:
# mount /dev/dm-1 /mnt/nvme/ 

mount: /mnt/nvme: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. 

Still no luck... Any more ideas?

Answer (score 8):

After you did `cryptsetup luksOpen`, most likely you need to activate LVs if not active:

```
sudo vgchange -ay # Activate LVs if not active
sudo lvscan
sudo lvdisplay
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root /mnt
```

Comment: activation of lv group is a must for mounting

Answer (score 3):

Check `dmesg` output before & after making a mount attempt; if the disk is reporting errors when attempting to mount the filesystem, the superblock of the filesystem might be damaged and unreadable.

`/mnt/nvme` must exist as an empty directory before you can mount anything on it. So run `mkdir -p /mnt/nvme` before trying to mount. It looks like the error message is about the directory you're trying to mount to, not about the filesystem.

If you know for sure that the filesystem type is `ext4`, then `mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root` should display the expected locations of alternate superblocks you can try. (The `-n` option tells `mkfs` to just simulate what it would have done at filesystem creation time.)

Then you can try mounting with `mount -t ext4 -o ro,sb=<alternate superblock number> /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root /mnt/nvme` with `<alternate superblock number>` replaced by one of the alternate superblock numbers indicated by the previous command.

Comment: Hi telcoM, thanks for still being with me! 
First did:
`# mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root
...
Superblock backups stored on blocks:  32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 102400000, 214990848`
Did it with al given numbers, but unfortunately none of them worked...
Before this dmesg didn't log any output, now i get:` [172412.145173] EXT4-fs (dm-1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`

Comment: I think I know what happened, was going to reinstall Kubuntu and came to the poimt where you have to partition your disk. I wanted to make it a LVM partitioned filesystem with full encryption, but at the last moment I decided to first try to get my data back. Somehow the installer must have been a little to eager and already  started to partition. So when I cancelled it didn't revert back correctly. Is this a possibility?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a very real possibility. When setting up an encrypted disk partition, the recommended practice is to first fill the disk with random data, to make it hard to even see what blocks are actually used and what are unused, if you don't have the encryption key or passphrase. This takes a long time, so it is reasonable to think that the installer may have started that part of the process as soon as you confirmed that you want to encrypt the disk. If the old install was also encrypted, its encryption master key is now probably overwritten and so the data is effectively lost.

Comment: If the old install did not use disk encryption, you might try [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or similar recovery software to search for any files that did not yet get overwritten. But if the old install was also encrypted, then without the encryption master key (located in the LUKS header of the old installation) any remaining old files are now practically indistinguishable from random bits, assuming that any reasonably strong encryption scheme was used.

Comment: Fortunately the old install wasn't encrypted, so will try my luck with your recommendation. Thanks for the info and help, much appreciated!